# Is it possible to progressively enhance image quality while zooming in safari mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

Is there any JavaScript/jQuery plugin that can take large images and enhance the quality while zooming? something like google earth/maps?

I want to use it in mobile browser, but a desktop solution will do too

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any plugin to do this, but it's quite easy in theory :

To know the zoom in mobile Safari, you only have to check this ratio : `document.body.clientWidth / window.innerWidth`.

Then, it's only a matter of choosing the right event to listen to (resize, or maybe a touch event), to check for this zoom level and to replace your img.

Comment: Safari Mobile doesn't send scroll events until the view has completely decelerated. Guess it's the same with zooming.

Comment: So maybe a touch event listener. A bit more tricky, but doable I think.

Comment: Nope. You probably have seen gifs and animations stopping during scrolling, didn't you? Apple just doesn't redraw the view until deceleration ended.

Comment: And  by manipulating the viewport, setting incremental maximum scale, so that there are artificial "steps" in the zooming ?

Comment: Well, you're right, I just tried. It works, but it's kinda crappy. Pasted the code here if someone wants to try it : http://pastebin.com/0GtfihVu